# How to reproduce contour-style labeling with rasterVis::contourplot?

Tags: raster, r, dem, labeling, contour

I am currently working with a digital elevation model (DEM) of Mt. Kilimanjaro, Tanzania. The referring raster grid can be downloaded from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) (Country: Tanzania; Subject: Elevation). After extraction in the current working directory, I define an 'extent' object used to crop the countrywide DEM by the geographic extent of interest as follows:

```
# Required packages
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

# Spatial extent of Mt. Kilimanjaro, TZ
kili <- data.frame(x = c(37, 37.72), y = c(-3.4, -2.84), id = c("ll", "ur"))
coordinates(kili) <- c("x", "y")
projection(kili) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# DEM
dem <- raster("TZA_alt.grd")
dem_kili <- crop(dem, kili)
```

Now, I would like to plot contour lines representing isohypses in a vertical spacing of 500 meters. Of course, this can easily be done using `contour` from the built-in **graphics** package:

```
levels <- seq(1000, 5000, 500)
contour(dem_kili, levels = levels)
```

[image: contour]

So far, so good. Unfortunatelly, I am looking for a way to combine a 'spplot' object showing MODIS-based NDVI in the Mt. Kilimanjaro region with labeled contour lines derived from this very DEM.
I already tried to specify `sp.layout = list("sp.lines", rasterToContour(dem_kili)` inside `spplot`, but this approach offers no possibility to draw labels associated with the particular contours. Executing `contour(dem_kili, ..., add = TRUE)` after `sp`-plotting the NDVI raster does not display any contour lines at all (I guess because `spplot` is lattice-based and `contour` is not).

The status quo is that I am using `contourplot` from the **rasterVis** package along with `as.layer` offered by **latticeExtra** to combine the visualized NDVI data with labeled contour lines. Without the preceding `levelplot` (which replaced the initial `spplot` call), my code looks like that:

```
library(rasterVis)
contourplot(dem_kili, at = levels, margin = FALSE)
```

[image: contourplot]

The problem I am facing now is that I do not like the label style created by `contourplot`. Is there a way to replicate the `contour`-style labels, e.g. no labeling of small contours (for instance near the upper right corner) and interruption of the contour to avoid intersection of labels with lines?
Or is there a way to combine the output of `contour` including the really nice label style with `spplot`/`levelplot` that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the labelling style using the `label.style` argument of
`lattice::contourplot`. In my opinion, you should choose `align`. It is not a complete solution because it does not break the contour lines, but it is better than the default method.

On the other hand you can overlay two different contour plots with different cuts, line widths, and labels size.

For example:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)

mainCuts <- c(500, 1000, 1500)
subCuts <- seq(0, maxValue(r), by = 100)
subCuts <- subCuts[!(subCuts %in% mainCuts)]

mainCP <- contourplot(r, at = mainCuts, 
                      lwd = 0.8,
                      labels = list(cex = 0.6),
                      label.style = 'align',
                      margin = FALSE)

subCP <- contourplot(r, at = subCuts,
                     lwd = 0.3,
                     labels = list(cex = 0.4),
                     label.style = 'align',
                     margin = FALSE)

subCP + mainCP
```